# Delphi problem with "special" Font Awesome characters on Android

Tags: android, delphi, fonts

Delphi 10.2.2

> > Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example now available [here](http://zazzem.com/fawes.zip) 236k

I installed Font Awesome to use fonts for my "arrows" and such. I am testing with #$F359 (arrow-alt-circle-left).

Note that I am already using a "weird" font (Showcard Gothic) in my Android app and all is well [see Note <1> below].

I created a very simple test app that works fine on Windows. On Android, I am getting the new (Font Awesome) font for "normal" characters. But not for the "special" one mentioned above.

In both cases, it is clear that the new font ***is* being read in and applied correctly**. In Windows, I am seeing the "special character" as expected. In Android, I am seeing a [] "box".

Notes:

1. I am using (here, for testing, and in my actual app) a "hack" of unit FMX.FontGlyphs.Android. The hacked version is in my source folder. It's documented at https://firemonkeyblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/using-custom-fonts-in-android-delphi.html and requires the following changes:

   In the implementation section, add `System.IOUtils` to the uses clause.
   In procedure `TAndroidFontGlyphManager.LoadResource`, add the local variable `FontFile: string;`

   finally, immediately before:

   ```
   Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.create(FamilyName, TypefaceFlag);
   ```

add:

```
    FontFile := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + CurrentSettings.Family + '.ttf';
    if FileExists(FontFile) then
    Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.createFromFile(StringToJString(FontFile))
    else
```

2. I copied the actual font file (Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf) into my source folder and renamed it "fawes.ttf".

   To ensure the changed extension wasn't causing my problem, I changed it back to ".otf" and made the associated change in FMX.FontGlyphs.Android. No change.
3. I added this ".ttf" file to my Deployment.

Finally, the app:

It's one form. Two labels. One button.

For each label, I set: AutoSize = True, StyledSettings = [], TextSettings.Font.Size = 32

I set the Position.X properties for the 2 labels equal, placing Label1 just above Label2.

Finally, the event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    FAMILY = 'Font Awesome 5 Free Solid';
  {$ELSE}
    FAMILY = 'fawes';
  {$ENDIF}
begin
Label1.Text := 'az';
Label2.Text := 'az' + widechar($F359);
Label2.TextSettings.Font.Family := FAMILY;
end;
```

That's everything. Any thoughts?

Comment: "In both cases, it is clear that the new font is being read in and applied correctly". Not saying that it isn't, however what evidence is there that this is the case? e.g lack of error message(s), or whatever.

Comment: I mean that I can see it, see the font being applied. I created an image composed of 4 screen shots (2 each from Windows and Android). Note that I've played with this little app a bit since I originally posted, so there are a few extra controls visible. Focus on Label1 & Label2. See the screenshots here: [link](http://zazzem.com/fawes.jpg). And: no errors or any problems (other than the lack of actual character display) at all.

Comment: Sorry, but those screenshots offer no proof that the font used is actually the one you want. It's just some sans serif...

Comment: Might need a [mcve] so that it can be examined closer

Comment: Ok. Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example now available [here](http://zazzem.com/fawes.zip) 236k. It includes two fonts for deployment (Showcard Gothic & Font Awesome) and full source, including "hacked" FMX.FontGlyphs.Android unit. (Search for "<jd>" for my changes.) **This FontGlyphs unit updates a label on the screen to show whether or not a font is found. They _are_ being found.** Note: FontGlyphs unit has 9 lines of my code and UnitFT (the project's only unit) is 90 lines. Finally: FMX.Context.GLES.Android included to prevent Android shutdown error; you're probably aware.

Comment: A [mcve] is not a link to an off-site .zip file that is 236K. A [mcve] is as described in the [mcve] article (you have to click the [mcve] link to read it), and is contained as source code here in your question. If you can't provide a [mcve] as required by the [help/on-topic], you can't ask here about why your code isn't working. (You did see the link I provided to explain [mcve], right?)